# Experienced in web development. How to get started with iPhone Game Development?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I know nothing about Game development. I mean.. nothing.

But I have developed couple of good ruby web applications. I have also developed a simple iPhone app and its in the app store.

I'm interested in iPhone (specifically in that screen size) game development. How do I get started? What are the books I should read? Please guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have several options, but this are my personal recommendations:

First a very good book about iPhone programming, from the code master Aaron Hillegas:

[ios_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/ios_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide_nd_edition_)

then you can advance in more advanced stuff like learn the awesome Cocos 2D framework with this book:

[Learn-iPhone-iPad-cocos2d-Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430233036)

This asumming that you have already a good base in C and Objective-C programming languages, if not i will recommend you this book:

[The C Programming Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/)

[The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)

With this books you will have a good amount of fun, cheers.

Answer (score 3):

While I'd agree that the book is the best way to go, if you want a starting point, [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial) tutorial will walk you through starting your first game.

Answer (score 3):

The key skill that will make a difference is not more Obj C or iOS coding knowledge, but learning game design, what makes a fun or compelling game experience.  Books on the art and psychology of game design might be a good starting place.

Answer (score 1):

[Definately the best book you can get for game making on the iphone](http://cocos2dbook.com/)