# iOS Game Development

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Experienced in web development. How to get started with iPhone Game Development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728809/experienced-in-web-development-how-to-get-started-with-iphone-game-development)

**- Question**

I am an iOS developer working on business applications. I want to start development of games for iOS. My Question is from where to start and what are required tools for games development and which resource is most important. So far i think that openGL and core Animations are required tools.

Please guide

Comment: You should probably split this into two.

Comment: You should make 2 questions with a proper title for each. So it will be more easy to find your questions

Comment: Or post/search at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i am going to split it. please do help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the Cocos2d framework.  Here's a great tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/352/how-to-make-a-simple-iphone-game-with-cocos2d-tutorial

Comment: I appreciate your help but i need to learn from basics i mean i don't know about 3d space and transformation can i have anything starting from these basics and then leading to frameworks.

Comment: You'll find that you don't need to know as much if you use a framework like cocos2d because all of the openGL is abstracted for you and you just use native objective-c methods and the framework does the openGL for you.  You should be able to follow that tutorial and that same site (same guy) does some more advanced tutorials also.

Comment: Kobold2d (http://www.kobold2d.com/display/KKSITE/Home) could prove useful also as it adds some functionality to cocos2d.  There are plenty of tutorials around for using these frameworks, just do some googling.  I would start with the one I provided you...

Comment: Also, I would not even CONSIDER 3d until you have mastered 2d.  Even if you want to learn openGL, using a framework like I mentioned will be a great way to get your feet wet before jumping into the ocean...

Comment: If you want to learn OpenGL from the basics try "Learning OpenGL ES for iOS" at http://www.amazon.com/dp/0321741838

Comment: than you so much guys for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend a game development framework. This article is a bit dated, but does reference toolkits that still exist and are good:

http://maniacdev.com/2009/08/the-open-source-iphone-game-engine-comparison/

If you're not prepared to learn a lot of math/programming, then shoot for using a commercial engine like Unreal, where most of the heavy lifting is done for you. Their tutorials are a good place to start.

You should also want to start playing with [Blender](http://blender.org) and/or Google Sketch-up. They will give you a better feel for the things you'll need to know in order to use a pre-built engine....and both are free.

The [Unreal game engine](http://www.unrealengine.com/udk/) also has a free edition.

Comment: I appreciate your help but i need to learn from basics i mean i don't know about 3d space and transformation can i have anything starting from these basics and then leading to frameworks.

Comment: If you have never done any 3D and feel that is what you need for your game, then please understand you have a lot of learning to do. I'd start with some tutorials on Linear Algebra and Trigonometry. From there, you're going to need a strong understanding of low-level C programming (if you are aiming at Obj-C). Once you have a decent handle on those three things, you have a shot at programming such a game.

Comment: well thx for your help i am planning to do all these three things. I am already good at C/C++ and objective-c.